# Integrate App service with Sign-in with apple

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Identity providers are easy to add to web app but we have big problems trying to find out how to add Sign-in with Apple, which is now a requirement for all new apps. This link describes Azure AD B2C. 
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-apple

Not being an Active directory expert, how can we integrate apple sign-in with web apps, just like adding Facebook or Google login? I think AAD B2C is a completely non-compatible solution vs EasyAuth in Azure web apps.

I would like to eventually see the a token and sid:xxx from EasyAuth with Sign-in with apple